# Data is not being added to listView?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, fragment

I've got an activity with two fragments. One is a fragment for doing input, the other one puts data in a listview based on the input.

In my activity I got this method which is called by the input-fragment:

```
public void deliverOutput(int position, int[] output){
    TabFragment2 listFrag = (TabFragment2) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.listFragment);
    if(listFrag != null){
       listFrag.receiveOutput(output);
    }
    else{
        //not relevant for this post
    }
}
```

The method gets an instance of the list-fragment and calls the method receiveOutput(output) to send the int-array it got by the method-call in the other fragment.

```
    public class TabFragment2 extends ListFragment {

    ArrayList<String> inputList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_2, container, false);

        String[] test = {"asdf", "qwer", "yxcv"};

        inputList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(test));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_standard, inputList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return v;
    }

    public void receiveOutput(int[] o){
        adapter.add(getString(R.string.listitemstr, o[0], o[1], o[2]));
        Log.d("CC", "Output received.");
    }
}
```

This is my code of the listFragment. Actually, the receiveOutput-method is supposed to add the data of the array to the listview now. But it is not being added to the listview even though adapter.add(...) is being called. The data of the String[] test are displayed. 
I guess I made a mistake in one of the code-pieces I showed above, but I don't know why the adapter.add(...) does not add data to the list.

---

EDIT:
I did some testings and it looks like the changes made in the method are not being applied, but I still don't know why. The method is being executed.  In other words: It seems like the method is declared as static, but it actually isn't.

Comment: I think there might be a better way to do this instead of keeping methods in fragments calling methods in activities; have you considered events?

Comment: not yet. i looked up "communicating with other fragments" on developers.android.com and that is basically the way it's being done there. but i don't think the communication is the problem, because the method in the listfragment is actually being executed, but somehow the listitem-adding does not work ...

Comment: So after adding items to the adapter, you call notifydataSetChanged() and what if you reload the list?

Comment: Where do you call deliverOutput? If you use AsyncTask make sure that you call that function in onPostExecute(..)

Comment: @Eenvincible calling notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't change anything for me. refreshing the list with getListView().invalidateViews() doesn't change anything as well.